# PIp installation urllib3 not found

Tags: python

I installed python 3.0 in my windows7 and I'm trying to install the pip from the file **get-pip.py** .while running this file it throwing an error like 
**import error:Nomodule named urllib3**.
I am trying to this to integrating selenium web driver packages to python in eclipse.

Thank you

Comment: How did you install python? It is likely that pip is already installed. Did you try `pip --version` or `python -m pip --version`?

Comment: Hi Holt, I installed python from exe file directly.pip is not installed along with it.im trying to install pip to add selenium driver to eclipse so that i downloaded a file get-pip.py file and trying to run it then it is showing the error like no module named urllib3 Import error.

Comment: Where did you get this `get-pip.py`? Maybe you could try installing from source - Go to https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pip, download the source `.tar.gz` file, extract it and run `python setup.py install` inside.

Comment: @Holt i downloaded the tar.gz file and extract it and run the setup file using command prompt python setup.py it shown errror like import error no module named setup tool found. here i the answers page im attaching the screen shot of the error pls look into it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the documentation of get-pip https://pip.pypa.io/en/latest/installing/

> pip works with CPython versions 2.7, 3.3, 3.4, 3.5, 3.6 and also pypy.

Restart with Python 3.3 at least instead of Python 3.0

If you have a specific requirement for an earlier version of Python 3, please explain.

Answer (score 0):

I think as per below screen, **pip** is not installed in my system so im trying to setup it by python using **python get-pip.py**

[image]